# python prepend a root URL to relative links

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working on a web scraping project and have a list of URLs.  Some of the URLs are relative URL's and I need to add the root URL ('https://www.census.gov') in front of any returned relative URL value starting with ('/').  Here is my for loops:

```
links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
records = []
for results in links:
    url = results['href']
    records.append(url)
```

I think I have the start of the if statement down:

```
if url.startswith('/'):
```

But not sure how to finish it.
Any tips or guidance appreciated!

Thanks,
Garrett

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you can try something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ROOT_URL = 'https://www.census.gov'

def scrape():
    r = requests.get(ROOT_URL)
    # soup = BeautifulSoup(URL, 'html.parser')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
    links = soup.find_all('a', href=True)
    records = []
    for results in links:
        url = results['href']
        print('URL: ', url)
        if url.startswith('#'):
            continue
        elif url.startswith('/'):
            url = ROOT_URL + url
            records.append(url)
            print('PROPER URL: ', url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    scrape()
```

It will add ROOT_URL in the front of all relative links.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than rolling your own, try [`urjloin`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urljoin) from the standard library. It takes care of relative and absolute URLs both.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urljoin
>>> base = 'https://www.census.gov/'
>>> relative = '/here/is/some/path'
>>> urljoin(base, relative)
'http://www.census.gov/here/is/some/path'
>>> not_relative =  'http://www.census.gov/here/is/another/path'
>>> urljoin(base, not_relative)
'http://www.census.gov/here/is/another/path'
```

If your absolute URLs have a different domain, though, you will need to not join those. In that case, you can just do:

```
if url.startswith('/'):
    url = urljoin(base, url)
```

Comment: I see where you are going with that but my records [] list contains both absolute and relative URLs, so I can't add that base variable to every record or i will double up that value for some of the absolute links.  I need to only add that base value to records that start with a ('/')

Comment: As long as your absolute links all have the same domain, this works just fine. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlparse) along with `_replace` method. This will work for both of your cases

```
>>> from urllib.parse import urlparse

>>> base_url = 'https://www.census.gov'
>>> urlparse('https://www.census.gov/path/to/text')._replace(netloc=base_url)
```

This will give you result like:

```
>>> ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='https://www.census.gov', path='/path/to/text', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

To parse with one without base_url, use the same method

```
>>> urlparse('/path/to/text')._replace(netloc=base_url)

>>> ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='https://www.census.gov', path='/path/to/text', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

To obtain combined url as a string use:

```
>>> url_comp = urlparse('/path/to/text')._replace(netloc=base_url)

>>> url_comp.netloc + url_comp.path
>>> 'https://www.census.gov/path/to/text'
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work with this:

```
if not url.startswith('/'):
    url
elif url.startswith('/'):
    url = 'https://www.census.gov' + url
```

Thanks,
Garrett